# MyBatis with Spring: Could not find result map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I cannot map the result of a query to a bean with MyBatis and Spring Boot using an xml file.

If I try to map the result with the annotation @ResultType(ResultBean.class) everything works, but I don't know how to map inner class, so I'm trying to map the result with the xml mapper.

I have this interface:

```
public interface MyMapper {
    @ResultMap("MyBean")
    @Select("SELECT myData as myData FROM myTable")
    public List<MyMapper> getMappedData();
}
```

And I have this MyMapper.xml file on the same package (the java class is in src/main/java/myPackage and the xml file is in /src/main/resources/myPackage).

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="myPackage.MyMapper">
    <resultMap id="MyBean" type="MyBean">
        <id property="myData " column="myData " />
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

This is the my SpringBootServletInitializer class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@MapperScan("myPackage")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Value("${spring.datasource.jndi-name}")
    private String jndiName;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource(jndiName);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource jndiObjectFactoryBean() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jofb = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jofb.setJndiName(jndiName);
        return (DataSource) jofb.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public ManagedTransactionFactory transactionFactory() {
        return new ManagedTransactionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage("beansPackage");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
      SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
      sqlSessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
      return (SqlSessionFactory) sqlSessionFactory.getObject();
    }

}
```

The bean is

```
@Alias("MyBean")
public class MyBeanimplements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3143220123058683967L;
    private String myData;
}
```

But it seems that MyBatis cannot find the xml mapper so it cannot map the result on the right bean. The error I receive is:

> 16:02:56,074 ERROR
>   [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter]
>   (default task-1) Forwarding to error page from request
>   [/MyPage/getData] due to exception [Could not find result map
>   myPackage.MyMapper.MyBean]:
>   org.apache.ibatis.builder.IncompleteElementException: Could not find
>   result map myPackage.MyMapper.MyBean

I'm missing some configuration? Maybe on the application.property file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in **< resultmap** **type** the CanonicalName of the class

ex. MyBean pkg is : org.mypkg.MyBean :

```
 <resultMap id="MyBean" type="org.mypkg.MyBean">
    <id property="myData " column="myData " />
</resultMap>
```

Comment: I've tryed it but the result is the same.

Comment: In @MapperScan("") try to specify the CanonicalName of interface "MyMapper"

Comment: If I try to do that the deploy fails: Spring cannot autowire myMapper like it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: I've used, for the xml mapper files, a dotted path (identical to the java mapper package name) but the path needs to be a normal path (with slashes and not dots).

Answer (score 0):

1st thing is your bean class should have the getters and setters.

if you want to use an inner class as the bean, you have to use the `$` sign to the path of your inner class like below.

```xml
<mapper namespace="myPackage.MyMapper">
    <resultMap id="MyBean" type="MainClass$MyBean">
        <id property="myData " column="myData " />
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

```
MainClassName$MyBean
```

```java
public class MainClassName{
   
   public static class MyBean{
     private String myData;
     //getters
     //setters
   
   }
}
```

the reason is that Mybatits check your ben files after compiled. the MyBatis can't find a class file named `MyBean.class`. your class file name after compiling like this `MainClassName$MyBean.class` so we have to use the `$` for that.